# scrollbar on fixed element only when height inferior

Tags: html, css

Good morning, I hava aiste with  a fixed sidebar. I would like that the sidebar is fixed always but when the height of the window is less than 660px (the min height of sidebar) appear scrollbar because if a user has a small screen it can't click on last buttons for example.

This is my css

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 660px;
    width: 269px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I have tried with `overflow:auto` or `overflow: scroll` but it doesn't work like my thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give the element a minimum height, by doing that you are ensuring that a scrollbar won't appear when the *document* is less than 660px in height.

Use `overflow:auto` and your scrollbar will appear only when it needs to.

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 269px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

I've also removed `float:left` as, in this case, it has no effect.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cr3RT/)

Answer (score 0):

i just checked it is working fine.

```
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
min-height: 660px;
width: 269px;
float: left;
position: fixed;
overflow:auto;
}
```

check the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3aK82/